# How to publish libraries locally on your computer with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have maven application which uses a library. I have the source code of both the application and the library.

I made a change locally on my machine in the library, and would like to test it the changes with my application.

What are the steps/step to do in order to use the modified version of the library in my application locally?

Both the application and the library use Java 8, Spring, Maven 3

Answer (score 1):

You change the version number of the library to something like `1.2.3-patched-SNAPSHOT`.

Then you build it with `mvn clean install`.

Now the application can use it.

Comment: How to change the version number of the library?

Comment: The `<version>` tag in the `pom.xml`